# Where to place catch block? SOAP Android

Tags: android, exception, try-catch

maybe this is kind of a stupid question but I have not been able to solve it.

I have a webservice that fills a list view. But I want the app to do some other stuff when there is no network connection, and therefore, no webservice communication.

I know that I have to catch an ConnectException, but no matter where I place the try catch block it won't catch the exception, tho my logcat does show that exception.

Here is the code and below you can find the logcat.

Can someone give me some advice on where to place the try catch thingy?

Thanks in advance!

```
package com.android.trucka.directorio;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActividadPrincipal extends Activity {

    private ListView list;
    String[] listado = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad_principal);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        setTitle("Directorio");

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsvDirectorio);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {
                String seleccionado = (String) ((TextView) arg1).getText();
                seleccionado = seleccionado.replaceAll(" ", "");
                if (VerificaNumero(seleccionado) == "SI") {
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), seleccionado,
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intentLlamada = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    intentLlamada.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + seleccionado));
                    intentLlamada.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intentLlamada);
                }
            }
        });

        Thread nt = new Thread() {
            String res;

            @Override
            public void run() {

                String NAMESPACE = "http://android.trucka.com/";
                String URL = "http://192.168.9.86/SumadorWS/ServicioAndroid.asmx";
                String SOAP_ACTION = "http://android.trucka.com/ObtenerDirectorio";
                String METHOD_NAME = "ObtenerDirectorio";

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;

                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                try {
                    transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    SoapPrimitive resultado_xml = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                            .getResponse();
                    res = resultado_xml.toString();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // System.out.println("RESPUESTA: " + res);
                listado = res.split(",");
                // for (int x = 0; x < arreglo.length; x++)
                // System.out.println("[" + x + "]" + arreglo[x]);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listado);
                        list.setAdapter(adaptador);
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res,
                        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        nt.start();
    }

    public static String VerificaNumero(String cadena) {
        String resultado = null;
        if (cadena.length() > 10) {
            resultado = "NO";
        } else if (cadena.length() <= 10) {
            resultado = "SI";
        }

        return resultado;
    }
}

06-25 11:21:49.140: W/System.err(27720): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.9.86 (port 80): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
06-25 11:21:49.140: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
06-25 11:21:49.140: W/System.err(27720):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-25 11:21:49.140: W/System.err(27720):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
06-25 11:21:49.150: W/System.err(27720):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:832)
06-25 11:21:49.150: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
06-25 11:21:49.150: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
06-25 11:21:49.150: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
06-25 11:21:49.160: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
06-25 11:21:49.160: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
06-25 11:21:49.160: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
06-25 11:21:49.160: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
06-25 11:21:49.170: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
06-25 11:21:49.170: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
06-25 11:21:49.170: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
06-25 11:21:49.170: W/System.err(27720):    at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:46)
06-25 11:21:49.180: W/System.err(27720):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:68)
06-25 11:21:49.180: W/System.err(27720):    at com.android.trucka.directorio.ActividadPrincipal$2.run(ActividadPrincipal.java:77)
06-25 11:21:49.180: W/System.err(27720): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
06-25 11:21:49.190: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
06-25 11:21:49.190: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
06-25 11:21:49.200: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
06-25 11:21:49.200: W/System.err(27720):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-25 11:21:49.200: W/System.err(27720):    ... 16 more
06-25 11:21:49.200: W/dalvikvm(27720): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41316460)
06-25 11:21:49.210: E/AndroidRuntime(27720): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-678
06-25 11:21:49.210: E/AndroidRuntime(27720): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-25 11:21:49.210: E/AndroidRuntime(27720):    at com.android.trucka.directorio.ActividadPrincipal$2.run(ActividadPrincipal.java:88)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime the `HttpTransportSE` class throws `null` or `NullPointerException` and you cannot see it with your current code.

In the last line of your stack trace you can see that there is a `NullPointerException` throwned by the `Run` method of the second anonymous inner class ( the Thread ).

With the `W/` It seems that the first exception in the logcat is just a warning...

```
W/System.err(27720): java.net.ConnectException:
```

Try this:

```
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch(Throwable t){
    // Here you might see your exception
    if(t != null)
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Guillaume
I have tried the code yo gently helped me with, but the exception is still uncaught.

Comment: Did you check if the `ConnectException` is a warning or not? I had exactly the same kind of issue in the past, the `ConnectionException`was a warning due to a network/router problem and `HttpTransportSE` was throwing `null`...

Comment: Hello again, I managed to add a method that verifies the connectivity to the network and worked for me.
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Added a method that checks for connectivity

```
public static String VerificarConectividad() {
        String resultado = null;

        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            SocketAddress direccion = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.10.135",
                    80);
            socket.connect(direccion, 3000);
            socket.close();
            resultado = "CONECTADO";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            resultado = "DESONECTADO";
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```